# Annihilator of subspace, linear functionals exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

**Problem**

Let $F$ be a subfield of the complex numbers. We define $n$ linear functionals in $F^n$ ($n \geq 2$) with $$f_k(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n(k-j)x_j$$

What is the dimension of the subspace annihilated by $f_1,...,f_n$?

I am not so sure what to do here. By the way these functionals are defined, it is clear that the $k-th$ coordinate of any vector $\alpha$ in $F^n$ is "annihilated" by the functional $f_k$. For example, if I consider the standard basis of the vector space, $\mathcal B=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$, then $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$. I don't realize how to deduce from these facts the dimension of the subspace. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the $k$-th coordinate of any vector is annihilated by $f_k$"? Only a vector in $F^n$ can be annihilated by $f_k$, not a single coordinate.

Comment: In more down-to-earth terms, the question asks you to find how big the space of all vectors $x \in F^n$ which satisfy $f_1(x) = f_2(x) = ... = f_n(x) = 0$ is. While $f_1(x) = f_2(x) = ... = f_n(x) = 0$ are $n$ linear equations on the coordinates of $x$, it can happen (and most often it does!) that they are linearly dependent, and so the space is bigger than it might first appear.

Answer (score 3):

You can try thinking of the linear transformation $A: F^n \rightarrow F^n$ which is made up of the $n$ functionals, i.e.,

$Ax = (f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x))$

and so the question becomes finding the dimension of the kernel. With respect to the standard basis, in the special case $n=4$, $A$ has matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & -1 & -2 & -3 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -2 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Row reduce using the second row to see what the rank is. Your answer for the rank will hold for all $n$, not just 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've calculated for $n=2,3,4,5$ and the dimension for these cases is $2$, now, I've tried to show that the dimension is $2$ for every $n$ by induction. I got stuck at the inductive space, I want to show that for the $n+1 \times n+1$ matrix, the dimension of the row space is $2$, now, if I neglect the $n+1$ column and the $n+1$ row, by hypothesis, the dimension of the row space of this $n \times n$ matrix is $2$, but I don't know how can I continue from there.

Comment: Forget the induction. Notice that all the rows are in the span of $\{ (0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1), (1, 1, \ldots, 1) \}.$

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the following.

Notice that $f_s(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=sf(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$,

where $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j$ and $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^njx_j$.

If $\displaystyle(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \bigcap_{s=1}^2\ker f_s$ then $0=f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-f_2(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(1-2)f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Thus, $f_2(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-2f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=-g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$. So, $\displaystyle\bigcap_{s=1}^2\ker f_s \subset \ker f\cap\ker g $

Thus, if $k>1$ then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{s=1}^k\ker f_s\subset \bigcap_{s=1}^2\ker f_s \subset \ker f\cap\ker g $. Of course, $\displaystyle \ker f\cap\ker g \subset \bigcap_{s=1}^k\ker f_s$.

So, if $k>1$ then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{s=1}^k\ker f_s= \ker f\cap\ker g $.

Now, $\ker f\cap\ker g =\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n);\ x_1+\ldots+x_n=x_1+2x_2+\ldots+nx_n=0\}$.

It is easy to find a basis for this subspace.